# Uncertain about the "n" in Getis Ord Gi* statistics

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-statistics, clustering

The formula of Getis Ord Gi* statistics is [here](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-statistics/h-how-hot-spot-analysis-getis-ord-gi-spatial-stati.htm). n is supposed to be the total number of features.

In the numerator of the Gi* statistics, it looks as though it is comparing (by subtracting) the weighted sum of the feature values around i and its neighbors against the overall weighted sum of all features from a map.

I don't understand why the notation in the first summation where j goes from 1 to n, shouldn't j goes from 1 to however many neighbors that are surrounding i instead of going through all features?

Comment: Please note that you are referencing ArcGIS Pro in your question which otherwise seems to be about the earlier ArcGIS 10.x for Desktop architecture.  The documentation may or may not be suitable for what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm behind any spatial analysis tols in ArcGIS cannot know how you model spatial relationships therefore the spatial weights. That is to say if you assume the spatial weight drops to zero after a certain proximity to a cell, from that distance on their meaning to the target cell becomes meaningless. I suggest to have a look at http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/java/gp_toolref/spatial_statistics_toolbox/spatial_weights.htm.